# solr - Knowing what field caused the retrival of the document

Tags: solr, solr4

I have two indexed fields in my document.- Name, Comment.
The user searches for a phrase and I need to act differently if it appeared in the comment or the name.
Is there a way to know why the document was retrieved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box way to know the field match and Solr does not return only the field that matched the query.
It would return you all the fields for the document which are marked by the fl parameter.
If you want to check which field the query matched you can check

1. highlighting feature which would give you the field and the match
2. Enable debug query and the explanation would give you the match for the fields.

However, both the options can be just used for checking purpose and not the actual search as it will be expensive for performance as well as may also depend on the configuration